# Writing open interval as infinite union of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

When an open interval is expressed in terms of the infinite union of closed sets I usually see the index of the union starting at $n=2/(b-a)$. I was just wondering why this particular index was chosen ?

The thing we do the union is $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An intersection of an infinite collection of closed sets is *closed*. It can never be an open interval. Maybe you mean an infinite *union*?
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+1/n,b-1/n]=[a+1,b-1].
$$
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+1/n,b-1/n]=(a,b).
$$

Comment: Yes I meant Union. I still don't understand the intuition why the index is chosen this way though.

Comment: In this case you construct your interval starting from included closed intervals, in such a way that the left end moves to the left and the right end moves to the right while the index $n$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason is when considering intervals $(a,b)$ where $b-a<1$. Assuming that $b-a <1$, we obtain for $n=1$:

$$[a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]= [a+1,b-1]. $$
Noting that $(b-1)-(a+1)=b-1-a-1=b-a-2< 1-2 < -1$, this is $b-1< a+1.$
Some texts define $[c,d]$ for $d<c$ as the empty set, but others only define such closed intervals for $c \leq d$.

If it is the case that it's not defined for $d<c$, then we need that $a+\frac{1}{n}\leq b-\frac{1}{n}$, hence $b-a\geq\frac{2}{n}$ or equivalently $\frac{b-a}{2}\geq \frac{1}{n}$, and hence $n \geq \frac{2}{b-a}$.